# Keep Summary field deployed

Tags: nodes

I'm using the node's Summary field for article teasers. Although not mandatory, this field is being constatly populated by content editors for article content types. I'm trying to make it visible instead of Drupal's default collapsed state, but I've hit a wall on identifying the related JS function and how to modify it without hacking core files.

Any idea on achieving the desired UI modification?

**EDIT:** OK, seems like the */modules/text/text.js* is the file in charge of adding the link that shows/hides the Summary field.

Since I don't want to simply comment out or edit core files, I think I'll have to make a custom module to unset this js file and not allow it to be loaded. I'm no JS expert but by looking into the code it seems to me that this file impacts only the text summary. Hence my updated question would be:  are there any side effects to unset this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the default value for the field (under Field Settings), in the "Summary" field, you can put a blank " ". This will force the summary field to show up. If you want to do it the correct way, then you will have to check the Javascript that shows/hides the field.

Comment: Thanks Abhijit. I'll keep this solution under my sleeve in case I fail to produce a proper custom module.

Comment: And for the JS, I think you can use hook_js_alter to do it. You can copy the JS file and rename it and comment out the lines. Unset the core JS and add your copy.

Comment: After talking this through, with an content editor, the solution you provided in #1 will suffice. 
I'm setting that as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this through template.php.

Functionality: Strip out any js that you specify in an array in your .info file:

```
function mytheme_js_alter(&$javascript) { 
  $excludes = _mytheme_alter(mytheme_theme_get_info('exclude'), 'js');
  $javascript = array_diff_key($javascript, $excludes);
}

function _mytheme_alter($files, $type) {
  $output = array();

  foreach($files as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($files[$key][$type])) {
      foreach($files[$key][$type] as $file => $name) {
        $output[$name] = FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Then in your .info file:

```
exclude[js][] = 'modules/field/modules/text/text.js'
```

All that text.js contains is the summary show/hide javascript. Without it, summaries always show.

You can alter these functions for css excludes as well (mytheme_css_alter), which is handy to clear out Drupal core crud :)